# Creating Graduated heatmap

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I am completely new to QGIS.

The problem I have is not knowing if the data I have currently can produce the results of image 2, And if not what I need, or point me in the right direction.

Data I have at the moment is Kromfontein_poly.shp - boundary & Kromfontei_Lab.shp - points
(Image 1)
[image]

I would like to know if I could use this information to create a map like this
[image]

To produce this Graduated heatmap
[image]

Comment: that doesn't look like a heatmap - please [edit] your question to explain what data you have and what result you would like to get

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you add a link to your data?

Comment: @Pointdump
Yes here it is
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tjVVJ_w-zsXE45ZcdiBS3u-897vdWS1A?usp=sharing

There are 3 folders
Kromfontei_Lab
Kromfontein_poly (boundary)
Kromfontei_megabuild
I would like to know if I can use the Kromfontei_Lab and Kromfontein_poly (boundary) to create the Kromfontei_megabuild
I'm not exp enough to know on how or if I have the relevant data.

Comment: @Shadow Creates a grid, and clip the created grid to the boundary. Then, the number of points is counted by SJOIN the points with the generated grid ID, and a different color is allocated for each number of counted points using the drawing tool.
I can't remember if this process was done in QGIS all at once. But the tools for each step are all in QGIS.

Comment: @Urban87 Thank you so much for your reply, I was able to replicate most of the MegaBuild, but now I have a problem with having data in the grid where the points use to be, but now I need to interpolate the data for the other fields is that possible? because right now all other fields have NULL

Link to file called MegaBuildTry.geojson
Url: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tjVVJ_w-zsXE45ZcdiBS3u-897vdWS1A

Answer (score 1):

If a raster output is enough, a simple Heatmap will do the trick:

`Processing`->`Tools`->`Heatmap (Kernel Density)`

for example, if you want to "interpolate" on the mg_k field:

[image]

which can be then clipped via
`Raster`->`Extraction`->`Clip Raster by Mask Layer`

Maybe however you want to explere other options/tools, like `TIN interpolation` or `v.surf.bspline`, which are proper interpolators, and produce vector outputs instead of rasters.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose discrete mode instead of continuous in your settings.